# Premiere CS6 hanging on ExporterAVI.prm after an upgrade from Vista 64bit SP2 to Windows 7

Tags: premiere

How do I fix Premiere CS6 hanging on ExporterAVI.prm after an upgrade from Vista 64bit SP2 to Windows 7?  It hangs indefinitely but was working fine before the OS upgrade.  No unusual CPU usage or memory usage, it just sits there forever.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely related to an AVI codec not loading properly after the upgrade.  In my case, I had the Matrox VFW software codec installed.  Uninstalling it and installing the newest Windows 7 version fixed the problem.  Clean up your installed codecs and reinstall updated versions of the codecs you need and the problem should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - Premiere hanging on ExportAVI plugin during launch. I have upgraded my NVidia display driver . . . and everything else runs fine on my Windows 10, desktop.  I think the ExportAVI.prm is a corrupt file . . .when I delete it, or move it temporarily to another folder, Premiere starts up fine. (the file is located in the Premiere/Plugins folder.)